# Supersimple SuperGlobal PHP form information needed

Tags: php, superglobals

Just looking for some clarification, as I am still new to all of this:

I have created a rudimentary CMS. We now have to redesign it to allow for an image upload.
When I use my original form which I was grabbing all of my POST info from, can I update it to send $_FILE info as well, or do I need a separate form?

In other words, when submitting a form, does php create info for all superglobals, or do you need a different form for each?

Comment: Probably explained somewhere here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php - And you can only have one form for submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP imports all the elements of your form. You just need to access them using superglobals.
for example `$_POST['name']` stores the value of the name field in the form and `$_POST['age']` stores the value of the age field in the form.
You can now save these to your db in the same script.